# How to detect uncheck box and send db query with php

Tags: php, checkbox

Hi i am using the following code, and a simple one checkbox to detect if its 1 or 0 and if the check box is selected the value become 1 and its successfully working but when I am writing a code for unchecked box my logical task is not completing. the code is;

```
global $wpdb;

$myrows = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT value FROM wp_geolocationdet" );
$fchk = $_POST["geolocrun"];


if (isset($fchk) && $fchk == "Yes"){
    $updatetable = $wpdb->update( 
    'wp_geolocationdet', 
    array( 
        'value' => '1', // string
    ), 
    array( 'activate' => 'status' ), 
    array( 
        '%s',   // value1
        '%d'    // value2
    ), 
    array( '%d' ) 
);
}



if (!isset($fchk)){
    $updatetable = $wpdb->update( 
    'wp_geolocationdet', 
    array( 
        'value' => '0', // string
    ), 
    array( 'activate' => 'status' ), 
    array( 
        '%s',   // value1
        '%d'    // value2
    ), 
    array( '%d' ) 
);
}
```

but the problem is when It detects that no checkbox is selected it automatically make the value in db '0' despite i unchecked it or just refresh the page it takes it as unchecked. How to over come this problem ? is there a way to truly detect that user unchecked the box ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add :

```
if(isset($_POST["geolocrun"]))
{
 // Your code here
}
```

At the beginning of your code to check if page refreshed or submitted !

Comment: He `$_POST["geolocrun"]` this in variable now what is difference between these `isset($_POST["geolocrun"])` and `isset($fchk)` ?

Comment: When you check "if(isset($_POST["geolocrun"]))" you check if you submitted data ! and "if(isset($fchk))" mean if $fchk is send or not, but it return not send too when you refresh page ! So you will get 0 in your db !

Comment: now the unchecked option is not working, because it will only work if the checkbox is isset but if its not isset the function will not work at all.

Comment: How you send data to check ? do you use a submit button ? or use JavaScript ?

Answer (score 0):

Just playing with the code found the answer, it might help someone looking for this, the form and code is on the same page, so you need to provide a name to the submit button.

```
<div class="chsub"> <input type="submit" name="chsave" value="Save"></div>
```

and then check if it is being called or not.

```
if ($_POST['chsave']){
//do action
}
```

in this way on page refresh it is not being called so the values are intact and working.